# error with csv module and pygeocoder

Tags: python, csv, encoding, geocoding

I am geocoding a list of addresses using pygeocoder. This is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
from pygeocoder import GeocoderError

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\L\Desktop\germanfdiaddress.csv', encoding="iso-8859-1")

address = df.Address
print address
add=[]
lat=[]
lng=[]
pcode=[]

for a in address:
    try:
        result = Geocoder.geocode(a)
        lat.extend([result[0].coordinates[0]])
        lng.extend([result[0].coordinates[1]])
        pcode.extend([result[0].postal_code])
    except GeocoderError:
        continue
    result = Geocoder.geocode(a)
    lat.extend([result[0].coordinates[0]])
    lng.extend([result[0].coordinates[1]])
    pcode.extend([result[0].postal_code])

fields= 'add','lat', 'lng', 'pcode'
rows=zip(address,lat,lng,pcode)

with open('C:\Users\L\Desktop\myfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    w = csv.writer(outfile)
    w.writerow(fields)
    for i in rows:
        w.writerow(i)
```

However I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\Dropbox\coding\python\geocoder with uft-8, with complete output.py", line 42, in <module>
    w.writerow(i)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas on what is happening? I know my code works except for the writing to a csv file.

Here is the csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yprg2u1ghuygye/germanfdiaddress.csv

Comment: You need to use `codecs.open` and set the encoding of the file you want to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv module has issues with encoding other than ASCII that are well documented:

> This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also,
>   there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters.
>   Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe;

As you are doing simple reads and writes, you can use the example `UnicodeWriter` class from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

Or, you can simplify your code thus:

```
import codecs

# ...

with codecs.open(r'C:\Users\L\Desktop\myfile.csv',
                 mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:

    outfile.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(fields)))
    for i in rows:
        outfile.write('{}\n'.format(','.join(i)))
```

Please use raw strings `r'C:\Users\L\Desktop\myfile.csv'` when you are using `\` as the path separator. This is to prevent things like `'C:\newfile` from being interpreted incorrectly.

You can also use forward slashes (even in Windows), which will eliminate the need to use raw strings.

Alternately, you can use `os.path.join` to build your file paths.

The point being, avoid using `\`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using a different approach but is always good to have more options.

Answer (score 1):

So I just changed the csv module for the unicodecsv and it works perfectly. Here is the new code:

```
import unicodecsv 
import pandas as pd 
from pygeocoder import Geocoder 
from pygeocoder import GeocoderError 

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\L\Desktop\germanfdiaddress.csv', encoding="iso-8859-1") 

address = df.Address 
print address 
add=[] 
lat=[] 
lng=[] 
pcode=[] 

for a in address: 
    try: 
        result = Geocoder.geocode(a) 
        lat.extend([result[0].coordinates[0]]) 
        lng.extend([result[0].coordinates[1]]) 
        pcode.extend([result[0].postal_code]) 
    except GeocoderError: 
        continue


fields= 'add','lat', 'lng', 'pcode'
rows=zip(address,lat,lng,pcode) 

with open('C:\Users\L\Desktop\myfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile: 
    w =  unicodecsv.writer(outfile, encoding='iso-8859-1') 
    w.writerow(fields) 
    for i in rows: 
        w.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a cleaner Pythonic look, you can use [Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) on GitHub & PyPi instead of pygeocoder, also to deal with the Unicode issues [UnicodeCSV](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) is really amazing, you can keep the same look in feel of DictWriter & DictReader, here's a code example:

```
import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging

# CSV Writer
csvfile = open('address_out.csv', 'wb')
fieldnames = ['source', 'address', 'lat', 'lng', 'postal']
writer = unicodecsv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, encoding='utf-8')
writer.writeheader()

# CSV Reader
with open('address.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    for line in reader:
        address = line['Address']

        # Geocoding
        g = geocoder.google(address)
        if g.ok:
            row = {}
            row['source'] = address
            row['address'] = g.address
            row['lat'] = g.lat
            row['lng'] = g.lng
            row['postal'] = g.postal
            writer.writerow(row)
            logging.info('Geocoding SUCCESS: ' + address)
        else:
            logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: ' + address)
```